# Finally found an old transaction from 2009

Tags: private-key

The file contains the addrStr
Balance
Amount sent (0)
And such and then 2 transactions

The address does show the 50 bitcoin.
One of the 2 transactions also show the same.
However I’m not sure how to get the priv key from this.
The second transaction it shows is not recognized by block explorer.
Is that a hash of the priv.key? I ran it threw sha256 but still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin transactions and addresses are public knowledge; there is no way to calculate a private key by looking at a transaction/address.

You'll need to find the private keys themselves, otherwise your coins will remain un-spendable.